# What's a word for a statement that is either true or false?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

"The Earth is big." is an opinion.

"Earth is 10 miles in diameter" is something that can be proven either true or false. It's not a fact, because facts are true. Is there a word for a statement that isn't an opinion? In other words, a statement that is either true or false.

Comment: _hypothesis, conjecture_, or any number of synonyms. Please go through them yourself. :)

Comment: The point is that such a statement can be refuted through the proper collection and analysis of data (or some equivalent research approach).  A statement that the earth is big is more than an opinion if the statement is that it is big is in comparison to other objects relevant in some way--in relation to other planetary systems around others suns (stars).

Comment: A *concrete* statement? Please look up 'concrete vs abstract' and 'general vs specific' (meanings and difference)

Comment: @English Student What is a "concrete statement"? The fact is that facts are always relative. Even 1 + 1 = 2, is only true if you are using a denary system of counting. In binary 1 + 1 = 11. Hence *ipso facto* (by the fact alone) there are no facts. Or are there? Pythagoras is only true on a level plain, isn't it?

Comment: @WS2 yes indeed everything is relative. [As somebody notoriously said (I dont know if its true or not) 'Einstein discovered relativity; even Einstein's wife was (his) relative!'] By the same reasoning some statements are **more concrete** *relative to others*. I think OP considers statements like 'the earth is big' to be very generalised and incapable of either definition or investigation. Relative to such, 'the earth is 10 miles in diameter' is a 'more concrete' (or 'more specific') statement that OP could somehow put to the test, to prove or disprove its validity / accuracy.

Comment: OP please see the excellent answer of Evan, whose suggestion **verifiable** is the best, literal and simplest adjective for your case, as in *"Earth is 10 miles in diameter" is a* ***verifiable*** *statement -- it can be proved either true or false.* 'Empirical' suggested by Evan is also a good option. If you need a noun, the right word is **empiricism** http://www.dictionary.com/browse/empiricism which is defined as "(4) an empirical conclusion" where **empirical** means "(3)provable or verifiable by experience or experiment" http://www.dictionary.com/browse/empirical

Comment: Perhaps "Boolean" is a possible word. NOUN
computing:
a binary variable, having two possible values called “true” and “false.”.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a word for a statement that isn't an opinion? In other words,
>   a statement that is either true or false.

I would call it a [***factual***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/factual) statement.

> Something that is *factual* is concerned with facts or contains facts,
>   rather than giving theories or personal interpretations.

Comment: Good choice, and keeps it simple! In the question OP however seems to assert that a factual statement must necessarily be true: *"... something that can be proven either true or false. It's not a fact, because facts are true."*

Comment: @EnglishStudent A false factual statement is still a factual statement.

Comment: In this case, _factual_ is only saying that the statement concerns facts, not whether or not those facts are true.  Unfortunately, however, some people may assume that _factual statement_ means _true statement_ so one my want to be careful when using the term.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Can a statement which is definitely not true be considered a fact? I think not.

Comment: @Evan -- Well, in the US today, I'm afraid the answer is yes...   But other than that, no, it cannot be considered a fact.  Such a statement, however, is [_concerned with what is actually the case_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/factual) (whether or not it is correct) so it is a factual statement.  I will agree that the term is not used that way generally speaking, hence my caveat to be careful using it.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn I don't understand why you assume "whether or not it is correct" to be implied in that definition, or why you would take *anything* to be implied in a definition in the dictionary. I think you're interpreting the definition too liberally. In fact, if you look at the [MW definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/factual), and we agree that a "fact" is true, then it's even harder to argue that "factual" has the meaning you suggest.

Comment: @Evan There is a difference between a fact and a factual statement. A factual statement can definitely be false; in fact, you could not have a libel law otherwise. Some claim that a fact *must* be true, but that too is wrong - that's just one of the meanings of the word.

Comment: Yes, I see that your answer makes that claim, but without giving any convincing evidence.

Comment: @Evan My answer is not about the meaning of *fact*, so this is irrelevant.

Comment: I see that the phrase "false factual statement" is synonymous with "false statement of fact," a phrase which is used in a legal setting to denote an incorrect claim which was made as though it were true. But (hopefully) not to belabor the point, I have two followup questions: (1) it seems that in the legal context a "false factual statement" has still been *presented* as true (is that the case?), and (2) Would the word be used this way in lay English, in the same way that (for example) "objective" would be?

Comment: @Evan A factual statement is a statement that purports to state the facts. I am not aware of any differences in its meaning in a legal context as opposed to ordinary use.

Answer (score 2):

***[Claim](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/claim?s=t)***

> an assertion of something as a fact

*(Dictionary.com)*

Answer (score 1):

I think the word which best complements the word "opinion" is "[belief](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belief):"

> conviction of the truth of some statement or the reality of some being
>   or phenomenon especially when based on examination of evidence.

An opinion is a way that someone feels about something, and a belief is something that some person (or some animal, I guess) thinks is true. They're both the same in that people *have* them.

However, based on the way you worded your question, it seems like you're just looking for a word which refers to an objective statement without calling that statement a fact. In that case you could use "[proposition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proposition):"

> An expression in language or signs of something that can be believed,
>   doubted, or denied or is either true or false

or maybe "hypothesis."

A possible adjective to describe statements which are either true or false is "[Objective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objective):"

> Expressing or dealing with facts or conditions as perceived without
>   distortion by personal feelings, prejudices, or interpretations.

Another word, "[empirical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empirical):"

> Capable of being verified or disproved by observation or experiment

I don't really like here, because in my experience, "empirical" is typically used to refer to a proposition which can not be reasoned about (i.e. requires data collection).

I think "[verifiable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verifiable):"

> capable of being verified

has a similar problem, because there are statements which are objective but not verifiable (i.e. "God exists.")

Comment: +1 for a really good answer! All your options are good, but sometimes we tend not see the best word (until you pointed it out) though it's quite obvious -- the best, literal and simplest fit for OP's question, I now realise, is your suggestion **verifiable.**

Comment: I don't actually like "verifiable" very much for this case. First, I believe OP is asking for a noun. Second, it's easy make a proposition (or hold a belief) that is not verifiable (by humans). For example: "God exist." I really think "proposition" and "belief" are the right words; the best one to use depends on the context.

Comment: Reading the question again, I see that OP specifically wants a word that means "statement that is either true or false" which is basically a 'verifiable statement' or an 'empirical statement' -- in fact there is a word called 'empiricism' with this meaning [see meaning 4 here: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/empiricism ] 
 that might be the ideal word for OP?!

Answer (score 0):

> Binary is the term which represent two values. So question which can have only two possible outcomes can be termed as Binary Questions.
>
> For example: Questions which can have answer like True/False, Yes/No are Binary Questions.

Source: [Quora: What is a binary question?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-binary-question)

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple "**dichotomy**". In the case of your example, the dichotomy is either "*true*" or "*false*". It is the basis for what is known as a "**dichotomous key**".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dichotomy

https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomous_key